# Return rows from one of the left outer join table if it fails

Tags: sql, oracle

I would to create a table as a join of this two tables

```
Table A
[Entity]    [Name]    [Date]
   123        A     13/10/2015
   123        B     13/10/2015
   123        C     13/10/2015

Table B
[Entity]    [Name]    [Date]    [Price]          
  123         A     13/10/2015    10
  123         B     13/10/2015    15
  321         B     13/10/2015    15
```

My request is

```
CREATE TABLE c AS 
    SELECT  A.entity as Entity,
            A.Name as Name,
            A.Date as Date, 
            B.Price as Price
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B
        ON A.Entity = B.Entity
        AND A.Name = B.Name
        AND A.Date = B.Date
```

This works quite well. I have the following result

```
Table C
[Entity]    [Name]    [Date]    [Price]          
  123         A     13/10/2015    10
  123         B     13/10/2015    15
```

Now I would like to do the same but also keep the rows from tables A (and use default values for table B) if the join fails. The result I expect is (if 0 is the default value for B.Price) :

```
[Entity]    [Name]    [Date]    [Price]          
  123         A     13/10/2015    10
  123         B     13/10/2015    15
  123         C     13/10/2015    0
```

Is it possible to do it in a single SQL request ? Is there some alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN along with Oracle NVL function::

```
 CREATE TABLE c AS 
 SELECT  A.entity as Entity,
    A.Name as Name,
    A.Date as Date, 
    NVL(B.Price,0) as Price
 FROM A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN B
    ON A.Entity = B.Entity
    AND A.Name = B.Name
    AND A.Date = B.Date
```

Hope It will work for you.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, he is doing that but mentioned output is wrong. i missed that. He just need to use NVL function.

Comment: The `OUTER` keyword was missing

Answer (score 2):

It is quite an unexpected result, since `left join` should keep rows that are present in `A`, but not present in `B`. So basically, you only need to handle the default value, in case there is no corresponding values in `B` and `price` is `null`, *for example*, using `coalesce`:

```
coalesce(B.Price, 0) as Price
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50979d/1)

Comment: you can use also `IFNULL`, `ISNULL`, `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Oracle's `NVL`-function is applicable too in this case.

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi IFNULL and ISNULL aren't Oracle commands, though.

Comment: @Boneist sorry i just filtered sql tags :D initiative of the user to check equivalent commands

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;) Did not know SQLFiddle. Really convenient.